# Delphi 10.2: TNetHttpClient BeginInvoke / EndInvoke

Tags: delphi, httpclient

Взоможно ли заимплементить асихронный http get / post запрос с помощью BeginInvoke / EndInvoke. Хотелось бы примеры,  но нигде не могу их найти - ни в Инете ни в help-e.

Comment: А почему вы не хотите использовать [TTask](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Using_TTask_from_the_Parallel_Programming_Library) из PPL?

Comment: Ну допустим, можно пример с TTask?

Comment: Примерно вот [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38593392), только Indy заменить на HttpClient.

Comment: Ну нормально, тоже может пригодиться, но хотелось бы разобраться с BeginInvoke / EndInvoke.